# Generate hash with custom names in perl

Tags: perl

Is it possible declare variables/hashes in Perl from an I/O list [e.g file with strings]?
For example, if my file look like this:

```
param1
param2
param3
```

I want Perl to generate 3 hashes with the correspondent names.

Comment: Yes, such structure is called hash of hashes. http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES

Answer (score 4):

What you are precisely asking, you don't want to do. It is bad juju to name variables based on input. There's a bunch of reasons, and if you want to know more, I'll refer you to [this site](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) which explains them.

Morever - it's unnecessary, given perl has hashes. Hashes are portable namespaces - they let you associate keys and values. 
Better still, the *values* in your hash can be ... hash references.

So you could read in your file that has:

```
param1
key=value

param2
key=anothervalue
```

And turn it into a hash of hashes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %params;
$params{"param1"}{"key"} = "value";
$params{"param2"}{"key"} = "anothervalue";

print Dumper \%params;
```

etc.

And then you don't need to have symbolic references any more. Your data structure would look like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'param1' => {
                        'key' => 'value'
                      },
          'param2' => {
                        'key' => 'anothervalue'
                      }
        };
```

Comment: That looks a lot like Config::Simple ;)

Comment: Yeah, probably. I wasn't entirely sure of the source data, so didn't want to steer towards any modules just yet.